# Designer HELP Release 9.0.1FP10 SHF315

Tags: lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

This very annoying and I can't figure how to change it.  When in Designer And I click on Help >> Help Contents from drop down menu it displays it differently than what I have been used to seeing and is very hard to navigate through.  Is there a way to change the behavior? I recently got new Hard drive with Windows 10 opperating system

[image: Designer 9 Help Contents]

This is what I am used to seeing and is very navigable:

[image: Traditional Designer Navigator]

Comment: you can right cliick an empty area and choose "help content". but now sure you can change this permanently

Answer (score 0):

IBM Support was able to reproduce this and is looking into the issue.  I did find a work around.

1. Open Help Contents from the drop down Help menu.
2. Right Click on the window and select properties.
3. Highlight and copy the Address (URL) line
4. Open a browser (not IE) and paste it in the Address line and go to the page.

It should then present it in a usable form.  If not, then click on the first content and that should do the trick.

A problem report has been created with IBM or HCL or whatever they are called now:  **SPR # ZNDNBA7TEV: Domino Designer Help Contents Display Issue**

[image: First Selection]
[image: Adress URL]
[image: Browser Window]